# Dónde ver los logs de una invocación a un ws soap? (Genexus 18 U1 - Java 17)

Tags: webservice, genexus, soap, log

estoy consumiendo en GX18U1 un servicio SOAP que se inspeccionó con el WSDL inspector sin problemas. Al momento de consumir no me da ningún error pero no me trae nada. Tampoco sale nada en los logs, ni del servidor ni de la aplicación.

Dónde se puede configurar para ver qué request y response está mandando/recibiendo GX?

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código (en texto, no imagen) que has utilizado.

Answer (score 0):

Posterior a consumir el servicio podes usar:

```
&Error = GetSOAPErr()
If &Error <> 0
     msg('Error: ' + GetSOAPErrMsg() ,status)
EndIf
```

Siendo en Java este log se va a escribir en Catalina.out

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta pero no me refería a eso, no me tira ningún error pero realmente no llegó a consumir el ws porque no me trae ningún dato. Quiero poder ver la invocación que debería hacer, el request efectivo y que está pasando puesto que no llega a invocar.

Comment: Para validar el request que efectivamente espera lo hago descubriendolo con SOAPUY y ahi puedo ver exactamente que le deberia mandar.
Para ver exactamente que le envie desde la aplicacion, uso un programa (solo sirve para comunicacioens http ya que las https van encriptadas) que se llama TCPTrace, es bastante intuitivo pero basicamente tenes que ponerle el puerto que escucha, el servidor de destino y el puerto de destino y prenderlo. Con esto podes ver exactamente los paquetes que van y los que responde para ver si estas armando mal el request

Comment: Suponiendo que la aplicación que intentas consumir esta en localhost y el puerto 8080, le pones que esuche en el puerto 8081 y cambias el location de Genexus para pegarle al localhost:8081 y el tcp trace va a redirigir los paquetes al 8080 dejando traza de los paquetes que pasan y que recibe.